# PHP redirect on submit not working

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

Many thanks in advance for even attempting to present a solution.
I'm having trouble with a simple html contact form.
The form's method is set to `post` and it's action is sent to a `php` file.
At the end of the PHP file the form is sent to, there is a basic location:redirection.

ex) `header("Location: ../index.htm");`

I configured my `php.ini` file (Apache) to display the php error(s).
This is what I'm shown:

```
"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/jwarddes/public_html/newTest/php/contact.php:2) in /home2/jwarddes/public_html/newTest/php/contact.php on line 20"
```

Line 20 of my code is my `header("location:...` redirect. This appears to be fine, yet something keeps throwing an error.
Needless to say, I'm stumped.

Could someone please try their hand at a solution or kindly nudge me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What's on line 2 of contact.php? That's where you're sending output (whitespace counts as output!)

Comment: [`stackoverflow - headers already sent`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent)

Comment: did you echo something before the header(...) ?? that may cause the problem

Comment: line 2 is merely my opening <?php tag.
I'm not making any echos throughout my function.

Comment: Maybe you have a session_start() in your page

Comment: Oh my! Embarrassing! "Line 2 is my <?php tag" There in-lies the problem! You cannot have whitespace before your code. Haha. Easy fix! Sorry to waste your time, but I would have overlooked that if it wasn't for you! Thanks a bunch, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is a common problem.

make sure you do not have any output (even a simple space at the top of the page) as that will send the headers prior to your redirect.

Possible Solutions are the following.

```
ob_start();
```

in the top of your page and

```
ob_end_flush();
```

at the bottom might solve your issue.

Also, I have this special function below which do a very smart redirect, try it out and let me know :)

```
/**
 * redirect()
 * 
 * Attempts to redirect the user to another page.
 * It tries to PHP header redirect, then JavaScript redirect, then try http redirect.
 * The following redirection method is only attempted if the previous redirection method attempt has failed  
 *  
 * @param mixed $url To be redirected to
 * @return nothing
 */
function redirect($url)
{
        if (!headers_sent())
        { //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
                header('Location: ' . $url);
                exit;
        } else
        { //If headers are sent... do java redirect... if java disabled, do html redirect.
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'window.location.href="' . $url . '";';
                echo '</script>';
                echo '<noscript>';
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=' . $url . '" />';
                echo '</noscript>';
                exit;
        }
} //==== End -- Redirect
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem many times before, I've seen solutions here and there which haven't worked. In my case I have put it down to the fact that I (php *include*) my pages into an index, which already has a header attribute.

The way I have worked around this is to use the meta method, `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<URL>" />';`

To make your page look a little better, you can add a one or two second delay and do something like...

`if ($ = $) { echo '(H1)Redirecting you to...(/H1)'; echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=<URL>" />'; }`

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any output (echo) send to browser before this line:

header("Location: ../index.htm");

Post your code, so that I can find out the exact issue

Answer (score 1):

From the manual: 
[PHP header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have anything printed out to the browser before using the redirect.

Anyway if you really want to do that you can do such trick:

```
echo "<script>location.href='...';</script>"
```

But that's not recommended as whatever you print out before you redirect cannot be seen by the user so why bother letting it out?

Comment: you can have anything before redirection, as long as you know headers needs to go first. Which usually means output buffering enabled

Answer (score 0):

its most probably because of a space at the starting or ending tag of  
check that I had the very similar problems when working on...